# Bootstrap Carousel Full Screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to get the image in the bootstrap carousel to show full screen but haven't been able to figure it out, I've been working on this for awhile and am totally stuck.  Right now I have just one image, but I will add more once it works...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Carousel Template &middot; Bootstrap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

    /* GLOBAL STYLES
    -------------------------------------------------- */
    /* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

    body {
      color: #5a5a5a;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }



    /* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
    .navbar-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 10;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .navbar-wrapper .navbar {

    }

    /* Remove border and change up box shadow for more contrast */
    .navbar .navbar-inner {
      border: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
         -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
              box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    }

    /* Downsize the brand/project name a bit */
    .navbar .brand {
      padding: 14px 20px 16px; /* Increase vertical padding to match navbar links */
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    }

    /* Navbar links: increase padding for taller navbar */
    .navbar .nav > li > a {
      padding: 15px 20px;
    }

    /* Offset the responsive button for proper vertical alignment */
    .navbar .btn-navbar {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }



    /* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Carousel base class */
    .carousel {
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .carousel .container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9;
    }

    .carousel .item {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .carousel-inner {
      overflow:hidden;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      position:relative;
    }

    .carousel img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }

    .carousel-caption {
      background-color: transparent;
      position: static;
      max-width: 550px;
      padding: 0 20px;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }
    .carousel-caption h1,
    .carousel-caption .lead {
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 1.25;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }


    /* RESPONSIVE CSS
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    @media (max-width: 979px) {

      .container.navbar-wrapper {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        width: auto;
      }
      .navbar-inner {
        border-radius: 0;
        margin: -20px 0;
      }

      .carousel img {
        width: auto;
        height: 500px;
      }

      .featurette {
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .featurette-image.pull-left,
      .featurette-image.pull-right {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        max-width: 40%;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
      }
    }


    @media (max-width: 767px) {

      .navbar-inner {
        margin: -20px;
      }

      .carousel {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel-caption {
        width: 65%;
        padding: 0 70px;
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
      .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .carousel-caption .lead,
      .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 18px;
      }

      .marketing .span4 + .span4 {
        margin-top: 40px;
      }

      .featurette-heading {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .featurette .lead {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.5;
      }

    }
    </style>

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                                   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.png">
  </head>

  <body>



    <!-- NAVBAR
    ================================================== -->
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <!-- Wrap the .navbar in .container to center it within the absolutely positioned parent. -->
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <!-- Responsive Navbar Part 1: Button for triggering responsive navbar (not covered in tutorial). Include responsive CSS to utilize. -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="brand" href="#">Treyca</a>
            <!-- Responsive Navbar Part 2: Place all navbar contents you want collapsed withing .navbar-collapse.collapse. -->
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="fluid.html">Beta</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <!-- Read about Bootstrap dropdowns at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
        </div><!-- /.navbar -->

      </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar-wrapper -->



    <!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="../assets/img/examples/Bar-1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- FOOTER -->
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2013 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
      </footer>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <script>
      !function ($) {
        $(function(){
          // carousel demo
          $('#myCarousel').carousel()
        })
      }(window.jQuery)
    </script>
    <script src="../assets/js/holder/holder.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
                background-color: black;
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**Update Bootstrap 4**

Bootstrap 4 has [utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/carousel/) that make it easier to create a full screen carousel. For example, use the `min-vh-100` class on the `carousel-item` content...

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner bg-info" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center min-vh-100">
                    <h1 class="display-1">ONE</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

[Full screen carousel demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/zS01LKKCUM)

This works to make the **carousel items full screen**, but carousel items that contain images or videos that have a specific size & aspect ratio require further consideration.

Since the viewport h/w ratio is likely to be different than the image or video h/w ratio, usually background images or `object-fit` are commonly used to size images and videos to "full screen". For videos, use the Bootstrap [responsive embed classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/embed/#aspect-ratios) as needed for the video ratio (21:9, 19:9, etc...).

[Full screen videos demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/Ce172fVBHP)

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58765043/171456

---

**Original answer (Bootstrap 3)**

Make sure the img inside the carousel item is set to height and width 100%. You also have to make sure the carousel and any of the .item containers (html,body) are 100%...

```
html,body{height:100%;}
.carousel,.item,.active{height:100%;}
.carousel-inner{height:100%;}
```

[Boostrap 3 Full Screen Carousel Demo](http://bootply.com/59900)

Here's an example for Bootstrap 3.x:
http://www.codeply.com/go/2tVXo3mAtV

Comment: Update for Bootstrap 5?

Answer (score 5):

This is how I did it. This makes the images in the slideshow take up the full screen if it´s aspect ratio allows it, othervice it scales down.

```
.carousel {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.carousel .carousel-inner {
    height:100%;    
}
```

To allways get a full screen slideshow, no matter screen aspect ratio, you can also use object-fit:  (doesn´t work in IE or Edge)

```
.carousel .carousel-inner img {
    display:block;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer on the startbootstrap.com. Try this code:

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 100%;
}


.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */

.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Source](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-full-slider/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without forcing `html` and `body` to me 100% height. Use view port height instead. And with *mouse wheel control* too.

```js
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}

var slider = document.getElementById("demo");
var onScroll = debounce(function(direction) {
  //console.log(direction);
  if (direction == false) {
   $('.carousel-control-next').click();
  } else {
   $('.carousel-control-prev').click();
  }
}, 100, true);

slider.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var delta;
  if (event.wheelDelta) {
    delta = event.wheelDelta;
  } else {
    delta = -1 * event.deltaY;
  }

  onScroll(delta >= 0);
});
```

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #212121;
}

.carousel-control-next,
.carousel-control-prev {
  width: 8% !important;
}

.carousel-item.active,
.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-item-right {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-item h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 72px;
    padding: 0 10%;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <h1 class="display-1 text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipisicing</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <h1 class="display-1 text-center">Inventore omnis odio, dolore culpa atque?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
     <h1 class="display-1 text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm had the same problem, and I tried with the answers above, but I wanted something more thin, then I tried to change one by one opsions, and discover that we just need to add

```
.carousel {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please explain how you arrived at your answer instead of just giving it so that others may learn from it.

Comment: Work for me!, but I think you should also change the dimensions of the images too,.. for me I change (or crop) all images into scale of 1280 : 720