# Bootstrap carousel as website background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, carousel

I'm using [twitter bootstrap carcass](https://github.com/artiz/Carcass) for my web project development.
Currently I have full screen background image which I set for the body tag like:

```
body {
  background: url('Content/images/planet.gif') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

It looks nice, and resizing works perfectly when I'm trying to change browser window size.

Now I would like to add some visual effects to my website by adding background carousel. Is there way to implement standard bootstrap carousel to the whole background?

I found a possible solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350902/bootstrap-carousel-full-screen), but what confuses me - is img tags which are using for different images. I was trying to do the same through background url's, but can't to figure it out.

Answer (score 16):

Problem has been solved. Source of code is [HERE](http://untame.net/2013/04/twitter-bootstrap-carousel/). It's easier than I thought:

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel container slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item one"></div>
        <div class="item two"></div>
        <div class="item three"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel { z-index: -99; } /* keeps this behind all content */
.carousel .item {
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;

}
.carousel .one {
    background: url(assets/img/slide3blur.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .two {
    background: url(assets/img/slide2blur.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .three {
    background: url(assets/img/slide1blur.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .active.left {
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:2;
}
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({interval: 7000});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the necroposting but have the similar problem. I can not figure out what are classes .one, .two and .three? They are not in the html. I suppose, they relate to the classes like "item two" but they are not submitted as classes. Could you clarify this?

Comment: @Moveton As a necroanswer to your necropost, CSS classes are space separated in HTML and not prefixed with a `.` but in CSS they are prefixed with a `.` so in this case, the classes `one`, `two`, and `three` *are* used in the HTML example.

Answer (score 2):

I would add to mbigun's reply to use this css to keep the images from jerking:

```
.carousel { z-index: -99; } /* keeps this behind all content */
.carousel .item {
position: fixed; 
 opacity: 0;
 left:0 !important;
width: 100%; height: 100%;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.carousel .one {
background: url(../images/layout/bgimages/homepage1.jpg);
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .two {
background: url(../images/layout/bgimages/homepage2.jpg);
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .three {
background: url(../images/layout/bgimages/homepage3.jpg);
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
}

.carousel .active {
opacity: 1 !important;
}

.carousel .left {
opacity: 1 !important;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s  !important;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s  !important;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.5s  !important;
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s  !important;
transition: opacity 0.5s  !important;
}
```