# Doing a background image carousel in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to do a carousel that changes the background image automatically. I used the code shown in this question: [Bootstrap carousel as website background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469705/bootstrap-carousel-as-website-background).

The image now is changing automatically, but the problem is that the image is moving along the page scroll (keeping static), and it messes the rest of the design.

HTML Preview: http://mirror2.gamerlive.cl/ts3_landing/

What should I do in this case? I've tried many variants but I can't get to make it static (it should look like the original background found at .intro-header (commented for viewing the carousel)

Thanks,
Rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

Well, just add the background image/color you want to the section you need it to be.

Like this for example:

```
.content-section-b {    
    background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, adding a background color to section-b fixes the glitch, but the image at intro-header keeps moving along with the navigator scroll :/