# How to fade loop background images?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Rookie here .. I'm trying to make my static background become a carousel.. my current html looks something like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="pageContent">
    </div>
</body>
```

and my CSS:

```
body {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/1600x1200') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

So I'd like to make the background now cycle images and stay responsive .. Can this be done easily using CSS3? or should I maybe wrap the contents of my html in a carousel with bootstrap? I wasn't able to find a good example of how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can: http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

Comment: know of any tutorials? never used vegas before so i'm not really sure what it is.

Comment: You can see: http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/setup/

Its very easy and responsive backgrounds :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/fakosu/7/)**

[image: Full page gallery fade]

I would do it using an `absolute` positioned `DIV` overlaying the `body`. 
Fade in the `DIV` with a new image, then set the same image to `body` and hide the `DIV` like:
<sub>(GRAY is `BODY`, SOrange is `DIV`)</sub>

[image: Responsive background fade gallery logic]

The increment of the current image Array is achieved by preincrementing `++counter`.

The loop fix is than achieved using *Remainder Operator*`%` to prevent the counter from exceeding the number of images in Array.

The loop itself is done inside `.fadeTo()` callback function by simply do a new iteration of the `loopBg()` function.

This is the needed CSS:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;} /* Global reset */
html, body{height:100%;width:100%;}
body, #bg{ background: #000 none 50% / cover; }
#bg{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

And the jQ:

```
var images = [
  "bg0.jpg",
  "bg1.jpg",
  "bg2.jpg"
];
var $body = $("body"),
    $bg = $("#bg"),
    n = images.length,
    c = 0; // Loop Counter

// Preload Array of images...
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
  var tImg = new Image();
  tImg.src = images[i];
}

$body.css({backgroundImage : "url("+images[c]+")"}); 

(function loopBg(){
  $bg.hide().css({backgroundImage : "url("+images[++c%n]+")"}).delay(2000).fadeTo(1200, 1, function(){
    $body.css({backgroundImage : "url("+images[c%n]+")"}); 
    loopBg();
  });
}());
```

***Edit:*** If you want to keep the background changing but make the content scrollable, simply add `overflow:auto;` to `#page` like in this demo: http://jsbin.com/huzayiruti/1/

Comment: just wow! thanks for the great explanation and visuals. I'm really going to try and get this working on my page. Might take me a day or so.. but truly a great answer ! Thanks

Comment: (I fixed a small issue in the code (preload images loop was off, changed `i<0` mistake to `i<n` )

Comment: i actually noticed that and was wondering .. haha also, i noticed you loaded the jquery in your head on jsbin.. i thought jquery always needed to be loaded at the very bottom of your body?

Comment: This kicks ass! Is there a way to use media queries so that I don't have to load the very large image on small devices? Should I start another question about that?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan this is so sweet but i have a small problem.. my page is really long so the background cuts off at a certain height.. i have set #bg to position: fixed.. and it appears to fix the problem only while the picture is fading in .. i feel like i need to set position: fixed to something else maybe .. i made a bootply to show u: http://www.bootply.com/hgxCjD3ATC#

Comment: @AlexDiVito you need just `overflow:auto;` see here: http://jsbin.com/fakosu/5/edit

Comment: @Christina thanks for the thumbs-heads-up! :) Yes, the 16:9 images are pretty small, 800x450. I would also dare with 640x360! what makes them look 'clean' even if resized is the opaque "pixelated" overlay. If you want to keep sharpness but at the same time you desire smaller images on mobile, you can detect the media on the first request using PHP and https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect -> change the images paths, et voilà!

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Thanks a ton for the help, i ended up using this method: http://untame.net/2013/04/twitter-bootstrap-carousel/

it was alot more intuitive for me since i am terrible at JQ and have been relying on bootstrap for basically all my functionality.

Comment: @AlexDiVito this is all it takes to change the effect: http://jsbin.com/fakosu/6/edit... I think I'll create a plugin out of this one with enhanced css3 transitions :)

Comment: hmm yah i can see how the JQ allows you to customize the way the background comes into view.. really cool! man i need to step up my game.. all in good time :P

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Hey, I have uploaded my website @ http://www.folio.uphero.com/ and im pretty pleased with it, except when i viewed it on my ipad.. the background was not full-screen.. it is repeating for some reason.. any idea why? here is a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/lAas6oYLLj

Comment: fixed.. not exactly sure how, but i changed this to:

body, #bg, html {
    background: #000 none 0 50% / no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

and it fixed my problem.

Comment: @AlexDiVito wow. Looks amazing! good job! (Just to warn you the images I used might be Copyrighted) :)

Comment: i am changing the images right now.. just wanted to make sure there were no bugs first .. also, is there a way to make the background image completely responsive? so that the full background image will show on mobile? or are there reasons that i wouldn't want that? thnx

Comment: Awesome, only one thing, how to choose random image? :D

Comment: @alessadro you don't need the `++c%n` and the `c%n` code. Simply a `c` that is generated at random (making sure the number is not repeated, would be silly to see to same images one after another :)) set as that `c` variable.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for answer! Now I have a similar problem of AlexDiVito, I'm using bootstrap, `oveflow:auto;` don't work in my case :(

Comment: @alessadro you're welcome to ask a new question - I'll try to take a look at it. (let me know here when you do)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks, this is the SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236477/how-to-fade-loop-background-images-in-twitters-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0):

**> Hi ! for that you have to work with "layers" and jquery, example:**

```
<div id="slider1_container">
    <div><img src="image1.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="image2.jpg" /></div>
   <div class="wraper">
          .........code
   </div>
</div>
```

*and in the css you have put the code for align the div in front or
 back ...  the jquery is like that :*

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = { $AutoPlay: true };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
    });
</script> 
and css like that: 

position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 1000px;
```

*> remember is just example, you have to modify the code for work as you

> need.and always exist examples in the internet you can consult here:*

[example slider background](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/fullscreen-jquery-slider.html)

*> regards I hope help you !*

Answer (score -1):

i ended up finding a page that had exactly what i was looking for:

[Bootstrap carousel as website background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469705/bootstrap-carousel-as-website-background)

will refer you to http://untame.net/2013/04/twitter-bootstrap-carousel/ and about halfway down the page will show you how to make a bootstrap background carousel without coding any JQ except for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({interval: 7000});
 });
```

amazing!

Comment: IMHO, tHe most horrible plugin you could find... you've found it! The carousel might work, but this is what it does to backgrounds: http://mode87.com/untame/demo/carousel/background.html (notice the *fade-to-white-cause-we-don't-know-how-to-work-out-transitions* effect!)

Comment: ugh well.. i ran into this problem where the background would disappear and just show whiteness whenever scrolling down the page so i am now in the process of switching back to Roko's answer! :P am having the same issue as before but overflow: auto; isn't working .. will make bootply if i can't figure it out soon..

Comment: fixed it.. thnx again

Comment: ah it was a silly typo at height: 100%.. i had height: 100$% .. so it just looked like it was doing some the same thing as before but yah the background looks amazing.. and i'm thinking of adding a layer to #page as you had in your example.. i had originally thought that each image was layered in photoshop but i realized it after going through your example a 2nd time that you just had a background layer set to #page.. cool concept

Comment: nice typo :) Photoshop has nothing to do with CSS and JS. I found 3 images on google, 16:9 format at 800x450px, set them to change with JS; but with CSS3 i made them full-screen using the `cover` value. :)

Comment: but that border around the edges and the layer that looks like it is just tons of lightly transparent dots overtop of the pictures.. i thought that was some CSS and a blank photoshop img with that layering or something. hm

Comment: nope, it's simply a Base64 encoded 4x4px png transparent pattern. see: http://jsbin.com/vuzubo/1/edit?html,css,output see my comments on @Christine comment on my answer. It's used to dim the background lightness and add more focus to the overall website text contrast. But also to make small images look good! The images are set for `body` and `#bg` (for the fade effect as explained in my graphic), while the overlaying `#page` has that .png to cover em all.

Comment: If you look closer, while the animation runs, the "pixelated" pattern stays in place, so it's not part of the image and there's no talk about Photoshop :)

Comment: this is crazy .. !! where does the png come from?? i've known for a while that i needed to darken the background somehow to make the text easier to read .. my site is looking kinda pro now :D

Comment: 1 last thing: what does <meta charset="utf-8"> do? is this for mobile viewport?

Comment: No, it's a way to say the browser to use character encoding as `UTF-8`. For example, me being from Croatia and using characters like šđčćžŠĐČĆŽ they would resuld as strange ASCII equivalents if StackOverflow did not used that same `meta` in <head> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: About Base64 encoded images you can find tons of answers on the web. If you want to get a base 64 encoded string from an image, to use as image or bg-image I've created a small tool: http://jsbin.com/jequq/1/edit

Comment: Here you can see how I used a simple `<img>` tag with a base64 string returned from that tool: http://jsbin.com/cipiqi/1/edit OK, it's a huge amount of text, but for a 4x4 .png pattern I like it! Remember that a Base64 encoded image is usually ~25% bigger than the actual image size.

Comment: very cool .. im gona play around with that mario head just to get an idea of how that would look on a website with another background .. but thanks a ton.. great info!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61175/discussion-between-alex-di-vito-and-roko-c-buljan).

Comment: Without any JQuery except it uses JQuery!