# Vegas background slideshow autoplay

Tags: jquery, slideshow, autoplay

I am using Vegas background slideshow (http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) and I need to make it autoplay instead of clicking on play button
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Not a plugin but... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799055/how-to-make-the-background-a-carousel/25800332#25800332

Answer (score 1):

does not need a library or plugin

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

```css
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
   </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[see example](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SimpleSlideshow/)</kbd>

another

<kbd>[only CSS and HTML](http://codepen.io/leemark/pen/vzCdo)</kbd>
[documentation](http://themarklee.com/2013/10/16/simple-crossfading-slideshow-css/)