# How to add multiple images in CSS?

Tags: css, header, background-image, css-transitions, transition

Hi I am new to CSS and currently I am using only one image in my header as you can see here:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("../../images/header.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7.5em 0 2em 0;
    cursor: default;
}
```

How can I add more images in the same header with transition effect in the same header only? I don't want to change the nomenclature in html of a header and want to control images through CSS

Comment: I need to learn that and that's my question. Sorry if it was not clear. I used javascript but it did not work. 
<script>
     //Array of images which you want to show: Use path you want.
     var images=new Array('images/header.jpg','images/bg01.jpg','images/bg03.jpg');
     var nextimage=0;
     doSlideshow();

    function doSlideshow(){
    if(nextimage>=images.length){nextimage=0;}
    $('.global-header')
    .css('header','url("'+images[nextimage++]+'")')
    .fadeIn(500,function(){
    setTimeout(doSlideshow,1000);
    });
}
</script>

Comment: All clear. But sadly it's not possible. Not using background on a single element.

Comment: This might be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799055/how-to-fade-loop-background-images

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:after` and `:before` to overlay additional two layers and transition those layers using `@keyframes` and `animation` making up to maximally three fading backgrounds,

Otherwise it's not exactly possible in the header only without using additional children HTML...

Answer (score -1):

you can do it by using background img : url("your url").
and you can add many images by using the same expression.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).