# crossfade effect not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i copied [this code](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/qEoKzZ) from codepen.io to add a crossfade effect to my site's background images.

```js
var bgImageArray = ["lonely.jpg", "uluwatu.jpg", "carezza-lake.jpg", "batu-bolong-temple.jpg"],
base = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/full-",
secs = 4;
bgImageArray.forEach(function(img){
    new Image().src = base + img; 
    // caches images, avoiding white flash between background replacements
});

function backgroundSequence() {
 window.clearTimeout();
 var k = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < bgImageArray.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   document.documentElement.style.background = "url(" + base + bgImageArray[k] + ") no-repeat center center fixed";
   document.documentElement.style.backgroundSize ="cover";
  if ((k + 1) === bgImageArray.length) { setTimeout(function() { backgroundSequence() }, (secs * 1000))} else { k++; }   
  }, (secs * 1000) * i) 
 }
}
backgroundSequence();
```

```css
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
html {
  margin: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/full-lonely.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  // blend mode optional at this stage; will be used more in the next demo.
  transition: 3s;
}
body { margin: 0; }
div#texttop { 
 color: #fff;
 width: 30%;
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 padding: 2rem;
 border: 4px double rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 font-family: Oxygen, sans-serif;
h1 { 
  margin-top: 0; 
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}
p { 
   line-height: 1.6; 
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 770px) {
 div#texttop { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="texttop">
  <h1>True Cross-Fade Background Images</h1>
  <p>A repeating sequence of fullscreen background images, pushed all the way to the root element. Crossfading effect in Webkit-derived browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera).</p>
 </div>
```

the images are cycling fine, but they aren't doing the cross fading transition, they're just changing without the crossfade effect. and occasionally there are white flashes between the image cycle.

i've inserted a snippet of the code here, and it still isn't working. perhaps there's something missing that i can't find?

Comment: Which browser have you tried this with ... if I recall, not all browsers support transitions in `background-image`

Comment: @JaromandaX i've only tested it in chrome. the original codepen doesn't seem to work in microsoft edge, but it works in chrome.

Comment: yep, chrome was the only one that supported background image transitions last time I looked

Comment: Since you code will not work in FF, IE and Edge... Here's a suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25800332/383904 with a nice graphical explanation

Comment: @JaromandaX i see, thanks for pointing that out. could you recommend a crossfade plugin that works in all browsers? squarespace seems to have one but their code isn't open source, this site has an example https://foxiebombs.com/

Comment: I didn't suggest you try anything, so, no need to thank me

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thank you, i'll try that!

Comment: @unilogue you're welcome, just, the answer is a bit old, instead of jQuery's `fade` you could instead use `.addClass`, `removeClass`, and let CSS3 `transition` do the fade work instead. Happy coding

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i ended up using your code instead of the one from codepen, it works beautifully across all browsers! https://thepeoplesday.org/

Comment: looks great! good job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

codepen.io is using [scss](https://sass-lang.com/guide) you should copy the compiled css,

```js
var bgImageArray = ["lonely.jpg", "uluwatu.jpg", "carezza-lake.jpg", "batu-bolong-temple.jpg"],
base = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/full-",
secs = 4;
bgImageArray.forEach(function(img){
    new Image().src = base + img; 
    // caches images, avoiding white flash between background replacements
});

function backgroundSequence() {
 window.clearTimeout();
 var k = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < bgImageArray.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   document.documentElement.style.background = "url(" + base + bgImageArray[k] + ") no-repeat center center fixed";
   document.documentElement.style.backgroundSize ="cover";
  if ((k + 1) === bgImageArray.length) { setTimeout(function() { backgroundSequence() }, (secs * 1000))} else { k++; }   
  }, (secs * 1000) * i) 
 }
}
backgroundSequence();
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/full-lonely.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  -webkit-transition: 3s;
  transition: 3s;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div#texttop {
  color: #fff;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 4px double rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-family: Oxygen, sans-serif;
}
div#texttop h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}
div#texttop p {
  line-height: 1.6;
}

@media all and (max-width: 770px) {
  div#texttop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="texttop">
  <h1>True Cross-Fade Background Images</h1>
  <p>A repeating sequence of fullscreen background images, pushed all the way to the root element. Crossfading effect in Webkit-derived browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera).</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: OP doesn't ask a way to transition method which is cross browser.

Comment: Once again, you're right!! damn my old feeble eyes :p - I'll remove my comments  to avoid my embarrassment :p

Comment: @ocanal i think that your code might have worked! the html css was the only part that was missing, it wasn't visible even when i disabled the css preprocessor option on codepen. i am new to sass so i'll have to figure that out.

Comment: @WillHoskings come on, can't you see that nested styling, https://imgur.com/al5Sbq4 ?

Comment: Oh yeah ┬──┬ ノ( ゜-゜ノ)