# How to make img with fullscreen as video fullscreen mode?

Tags: html, browser

As we know, the tag `video` has default control that can play video with fullscreen. It's a pretty watch mode. And I want make image `img` can be achieved this. I find a web can do this, but I can't figure it out how to  trigger the video fullpage mode when click a image in web page.

**Notice: Not make browser window full screen.**

Thanks for your help and [click this is link](https://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/). In a word, how to watch img with browser in this way as follow:

1. in above link, you can first choose **fullscreen**.
2. second, click the button **launch image gallery**.

[image]

Comment: Not getting what exactly your facing ....Please clarify the problem..

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen#7525760), than you can delete your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350902/bootstrap-carousel-full-screen