# How to get Bootstrap Carousel to fit 100% to screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I was wondering how to get the carousel in [Bootstrap's Carousel example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/) to fit 100% to screen, as opposed to the way it's displaying now which allows some blank circular images to be included in the main landing page when it is loaded.

[Here's a simple illustration of what I'm trying to get working.](http://postimg.org/image/uns0gla8z/)

page source (relevant bit):

```
<!-- Carousel
  ================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

carousel.css (relevant bit):

```
/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

I know the task at hand is pretty simple, and I admit that I have tried tinkering around with the carousel.css file for the past hour or so (changing various height position, z-index, etc. values), but I just can't seem to get the resizing to work without majorly screwing things up. More specifically, I tried adding

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350902/bootstrap-carousel-full-screen/16356665

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying to fiddle around with the current version of carousel provided on Bootstrap's website, I just figured that trying to find a work-around for their provided code would just be more trouble than it's worth.

So, I found [this example](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/) instead and just replaced the carousel HTML with [the one provided by their source - starting at the 'header'](https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-full-slider/blob/gh-pages/index.html) and replaced the carousel portion in the carousel.css with [their full-slider.css part](https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-full-slider/blob/gh-pages/css/full-slider.css).

Final code looks something like this:

**HTML**

```
<!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>

</header>
```

**CSS**

```
/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */
.carousel,
.item,
.active {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */

.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

IMO, this version is much easier to read anyways. Thanks to @K.C. for the help!

Answer (score 10):

You have fixed height for the carousel and carousel items. Then it obviously will be of that size.

Try this

```
html,body{
   height:100%;
}
.carousel,.item,.active{
   height:100%;
 }
.carousel-inner{
    height:100%;
}
```

[Look at this question for demo and more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350902/bootstrap-carousel-full-screen)

Even after changing it won't work then you can replace your carousel with this one here
[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/59900)

**Also via jquery** you can first get the windows total height and set it to the height of your carousel wrapper and other elements as accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var height = $(window).height();  //getting windows height
   jQuery('#myCarousel').css('height',height+'px');   //and setting height of carousel
});
```

Comment: No dice. I think the example you linked to isn't working because it is based off Bootstrap v2.3.1 (whereas I'm using v3.3.4). While I guess I can use the code in the DEMO you linked to, I'd prefer to find a solution for the current version.

Comment: I ended up replacing my code anyways, but used the example found here instead: https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-full-slider. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 3):

Kinda late to the party... but rather late then never I suppose.

Anyways, I took a different approach to this.

CSS:

```
html, body, .carousel,  .carousel-inner, .carousel-inner .item {
   height: 100%;
}

.Outside {
    background-image: url("../Your/Image/Path/Outside.jpg");
    z-index: -2;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="carousel1" class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">

<!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="Outside"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement, and I found that below bootstrap class pretty much does the job.

class="d-block w-100 h-100"

```html
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQMueyisr8wYKRW8wS4G19HmwvGg_T_j5U3LgBfSPmdUc8aq-AX" class="d-block w-100 h-100" >
```

:

Comment: Had no effect for me in Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy solution that worked for me.

Add this class to your image tag inside carousel-inner div.

CSS:

```
.carousel-img-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="img_url" alt="text" class="carousel-img-width">
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the media queries of the bootstrap class trying to set the max-width to a smaller size. 
You can apply a custom class to the carousel and override the max-width to fit the screen.

```css
.custom-carousel {
  max-width:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="carousel1" class="carousel carousel-fade custom-carousel" data-ride="carousel">

<!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="Outside"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```