# How do I make my Bootstrap Carousel the full width of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make my bootstrap carousel the full width of the page, thinking that that will look the best. I've looked it up and nothing I tried worked, though. Also, if you think that making it a different size would be better, I would love to hear! I'm not great with layout and I'm trying to work on it. Also, my pictures are in SD even though they were HD. Should I link them in the same folder as my html and css files instead of getting them straight from the internet?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website Template</title>
        <!-- links to the css page and bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<!-- BEGIN NAVBAR -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
                <li><a class="" href="#">Text</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Text</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END NAVBAR -->


            <div class="container">
                <!-- CAROUSEL START -->
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!--Carousel indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <!-- Carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="http://36646d87786feafc0611-0338bbbce19fc98919c6293def4c5554.r0.cf1.rackcdn.com/images/FiGZ9r3D3E82.878x0.Z-Z96KYq.jpg" alt="First Slide">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>First slide label</h3>
                                <p>BLAH</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/p/2/005/096/045/19d71d5.jpg" alt="Second Slide">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                                    <p>BLAH BLAH</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="http://d3psvddqt9zx7g.cloudfront.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/lol1-2.jpg" alt="Third Slide">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                                    <p>BLAH BLAH BLAH</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Carousel nav -->
                        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                <!--CAROUSEL END -->
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.carousel img {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    max-height: 550px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Just remove the surrounding `container`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350902/bootstrap-carousel-full-screen/16356665

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the container like in this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zdxq5c85/

```
<!-- CAROUSEL START -->
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!--Carousel indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <!-- Carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="http://36646d87786feafc0611-0338bbbce19fc98919c6293def4c5554.r0.cf1.rackcdn.com/images/FiGZ9r3D3E82.878x0.Z-Z96KYq.jpg" alt="First Slide">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>First slide label</h3>
                                <p>BLAH</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/p/2/005/096/045/19d71d5.jpg" alt="Second Slide">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                                    <p>BLAH BLAH</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="http://d3psvddqt9zx7g.cloudfront.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/lol1-2.jpg" alt="Third Slide">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                                    <p>BLAH BLAH BLAH</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Carousel nav -->
                        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                <!--CAROUSEL END -->
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Do you have any idea about the pictures, though? They are still in standard definition. Should I put them in my folder for these files? The original pictures are HD but they are showing in SD on my website.

Comment: I'm not quite sure If I understand you well. But, as I see you are saying that originally you have a better quality pictures (HD), but on the site they are appearing with lower quality. Now, I notice the image link is from some wordpress site, if this is your site then make sure that you are using the right link that wordpress generates (WP makes different image resolutions) else try uploading the images separately (without WP) and use them in the page you need