# Bootstrap carousel full screen on every device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

so i want a carousel that should take full height and width of the display monitor and then scroll down. like [this](https://www.yikyak.com/home), and the images inside should fill its parent while maintaining ratio. the problem is either i have to provide fixed height or it will take the height of largest image. so how can i make a carousel of full screen for every device.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my-slider").carousel({
    interval : 3000,
    pause: false
  });
})
```

```css
.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="margin-right:0px; margin-left:0px;">
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:0px;">
      <div id="my-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/image1.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="img/image2.jpg"/>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="img/image3.jpg"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="border:none; background:white;">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 image-container">
          <center><img src="img/image4.jpg" style="height:200px;" class="img-responsive" /></center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12">  
          <h2>Sample heading</h2>
          <p style="font-size:15px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed hendrerit adipiscing blandit. Aliquam placerat, velit a fermentum fermentum, mi felis vehicula justo, a dapibus quam augue non massa.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="border:none; background:white;">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-sm-push-8 col-xs-12 image-container">
          <center><img src="img/image4.jpg" style="height:200px;" class="img-responsive" /></center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-sm-pull-4 col-xs-12">
          <h2>Sample heading</h2>
          <p style="font-size:15px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed hendrerit adipiscing blandit. Aliquam placerat, velit a fermentum fermentum, mi felis vehicula justo, a dapibus quam augue non massa.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="border:none; background:white;">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 image-container">
          <center><img src="img/image4.jpg" style="height:200px;" class="img-responsive" /></center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12">  
          <h2>Sample heading</h2>
          <p style="font-size:15px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed hendrerit adipiscing blandit. Aliquam placerat, velit a fermentum fermentum, mi felis vehicula justo, a dapibus quam augue non massa.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      <form action="" method="" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id ="name" type="name" name="" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email Address</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id ="email" type="email" name="" class="form-control"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id ="message" type="message" name="" class="form-control"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-push-2">
            <input id ="submit" type="submit" name="" class="btn btn-default"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Carousel Full Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350902/bootstrap-carousel-full-screen)

Comment: you mean your image should always take 100% width?

Comment: you can also inspect [this](http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-full-slider/)

Comment: @tmg that helped. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `jquery` for this, As when your site load you need to get `height` and `width` of viewport. And then apply that `height` and `width` to your carosel.

use this code and change the `carosel` class for yourself.

```
$(function(){
   var height = $(window).height();
   var width = $(window).width();
   $(".yourCarosel").css(
      {
       "height":height, 
       "width":width
      });
});
```

It will automatically get the **height** and **width** of window and apply that also on the `carosel`.

Comment: by doing so i am loosing the responsiveness of carousel. and how should i maintain image ratios?

Comment: If the site is visited from mobile it will take the height and width of mobile. So you haven't to worry about that. Also the ratio will be according to viewport.