# bootstrap 4 carousel full-screen and auto-crop

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having issues performing the bootstrap 4 carousel on full screen when uploaded images are a bit long. Is there a way to make the images to be at full-width but cropped based on `position: center, background: cover`. I am trying to make the page un-scrollable in other words.

I have tried referring to this webpage: [Bootstrap Carousel Full Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350902/bootstrap-carousel-full-screen)
but whenever I tried another background, it just stretches and creates a scroll-bar.

Here is the github repo: https://github.com/celestialbunny/project1 if needed

Comment: Here is the link to website https://celestialbunny.github.io/project1/ to view the page

Answer (score 0):

try setting `height:100vh` to the `img` element. It sets the height equal to the visible height of the screen in simple words. `vh` is `viewport-height`.

If it was a `background` then there are some other options.

Thanks