# my website is not mobile friendly, only the slider is the one that is not responsive and l want to make the slider responsive,

Tags: html, css, mobile

my website is responsive except the slider which is not working, l tried a couple of solutions but still it is not responsive and none of the solutions provided to the previous similar questions helped

l tried using the html tags viewport .... and a couple of css for different devices but the slider is still not responsive

```
enter code here
```

## slider

```
{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
```

l expect the slider images to be responsive and fit in the whole page of mobile devices and tablets`enter code here`

Comment: website  address->     https://tavermcon.co.za

Comment: It looks fine as is, do you want the images to be full height on mobile?

Comment: yes l want the images to be full height on mobile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Carousel Full Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350902/bootstrap-carousel-full-screen)

Comment: thanks l used the solution the duplication it worked but kinder stretched the image resolution but it does not look that bad

Answer (score 0):

I cant see your slider on the site? Your best bet is to either use something like bootstrap or use a media query